# Run two instances of Linux on one server

Tags: linux, linux-kvm, multiple-instances

I own a secondary PC that I’ve been using as a server, my friend has been using it to host game servers for stuff like “Counter-Strike: Global Offensive,” but recently I’ve been trying to use it as a web-server / place for me to test some of my programs. And I don't want my friend having access to any of my files, but he claims he needs root/sudo to run the servers.

So I’ve been trying to get 2 separate VMs setup for the server, one for me to do whatever I want, and one for him to run the game servers from, how would I go about doing this without having to worry about IPs network switching etc, basically I just want one domain name to go to the game servers, and one domain to go to my personal server.

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at QEMU or VirtualBox. There are lots of good online tutorials. It would be quite a long Super user answer to take you through it from start to finish.

Answer (score -2):

You can use an Apache server (this is the server that listens on 80 & 443 and also handles the HTTPs trafic for both sites), that acts as a proxy and uses "Virtual Hosts" to forward requests for either server to their actual server (that can be a VM in your case).

Typical set up:

- Both domain names point to your server's IP
- The server runs an Apache server, and at least one VM that contains your friend's server.
- Requests to your friend's server (recognized by the host given in the HTTP headers) are forwarded to the VM:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        "/" "http://local-friends-vm-adress/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://local-friends-vm-adress/"
    ServerName friendsdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

- You can have your own server running on the "bare metal" or also run it in its own VM using a similar statement.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The core issue is the original poster and his friend want to share the server itself and both claim to need root/sudo access. VirtualHosts in Apache just allows two different hostnames to deliver content. Two people having root/sudo — while attempting to maintain privacy — is a completely different issue. The only way to achieve something like this is to have two VMs running on one machine and have each person — original poster and friend — just have separate/isolated access to each.

Comment: yeah that was my intention to get two vms setup and some how get the traffic from my domain to go to my vm, and his domain to go to his vm, but since my network only has a single IP its a bit of an issue.

Comment: @Chris This is exactly what this solution does. One single external IP, and forwarding request to the proper VM using the domain name from the HTTP requests. See augmented answer.

Comment: @jakegould The VM is assumed. My solution describes how to you route HTTP requests to the proper VM.